# MS Office Interop Word Копия целиком первой страницы

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, copy

Помогите с реализацией копии первой страницы целиком прямо в текущем документе на вторую.
Т.е. я имею шаблон, заполняю его через программу, всё хорошо. Но как я могу точно эту же первую страницу "программно" скопировать во вторую страницу в этом же документе Word.

Answer (score 1):

ну как то так:

```
Object missingObj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Object trueObj = true;
Object falseObj = false;
object missing = Missing.Value;

//создаем обьект приложения word
application = new Word.Application();
// создаем путь к файлу
Object templatePathObj = "путь к шаблону";
// если вылетим не этом этапе, приложение останется открытым
try
{
    sdoc = application.Documents.Add(ref templatePathObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);

}
catch (Exception error)
{
    //document.Close(ref falseObj, ref  missingObj, ref missingObj);
    application.Quit(ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
    application = null;
    throw error;
}

//тут заполняем шаблон

//копируем в буфер
sdoc.Range(ref missingObj, ref missingObj).Copy();
object missing = Missing.Value;
object what = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine;
object which = Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast;

Word.Range endRange = sdoc.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref missing, ref missing);
endRange.Paste();
application.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но не смог всё таки. Сделал заглушку с MessageBox чтобы тот перевернул бумагу и опять в Word.Documents.PrintOut(); P.S. попробывал отправить параметры в PrintOut результат не тот...